# Long garbage collection time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, dynatrace

Long garbage collection time experienced by our client in our java web-app (JAVA 8, Tomcat 9) and eventually the application gets suspended indefinitely. `Dynatrace` performance management tool log throws `Long garbage collection time` error quiet frequently. Server RAM is 32GB, the Heap size was increased from 1 to 4 GB, and still the error gets thrown but with less frequency than before. JAVA 8 uses parallel collector by default, so is there anything else that can be configured to improve the GC time? Longer GC time indicates large amount of memory objects needs to be recovered, and hence further adding memory may not be ideal.

Does setting `The maximum pause time goal` parameter will be any useful at all?
`-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=<N>`

Comment: Refactor your code so it allocates less memory on the heap? Or consider re-using created objects instead of creating new ones. Many ways to improve this but you need to touch your code and analyse it first obviously

Comment: If your app has a slow memory leak, then the system spends ever more time garbage collecting, because the amount of actual heap available shrinks over time, which means the time between GCs lengthens, _and_ those GCs need to be more thorough which take longer. Let your app run for a while, run a profiler and make a snapshot. Then let it run until its getting near crash-time and do it again. Compare the two, they should be roughly similar. If they aren't, voila, whatever thing is way more of in the second run, that's leaking.

Comment: 'Make lots of garbage' __is no longer relevant__ - the JVM can collect fast garbage at effectively zero cost. It's not about how much garbage, it's about what kind. Most things that result in 'hard to collect garbage' are code problems - unclosed resources, badly configured memory caches, processes that should 'stream' (use `InputStream` or `Channel`, but instead just dump it all into `String` or `byte[]` that are huge), runaway class reloaders, and so on.

Comment: How can we advise you on GC tuning, if you haven't provided information about GC options and GC behavior in your case? Please, add JVM options and GC logs to your question. Also, why you've chosen the heap size of 4GB, if there are 32GB available on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You first should understand what is allocating too much memory.

There are many different things which can be related, including memory leaks, unnecessary high memory allocation, large allocations inside loops or even actual memory demand of the application being higher than you think.

As you seem to have Dynatrace available, you can use ["Memory Profiling"](https://docs.dynatrace.com/docs/platform-modules/applications-and-microservices/profiling-and-optimization/memory-profiling) to analyze and pin-point which code-places are actually causing to much GC time here, maybe there is some simple optimization to reduce memory allocations.